# Compile Linux kernel modules with KASAN

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to use the Linux kernel address sanitizer (KASAN) with a loadable module, but so far haven't been able to make it work. I compiled a kernel with KASAN and was able to verify that it properly detects errors caused by the statically linked body of the kernel, but when I compile a loadable module with that kernel, the module is not configured for KASAN (e.g. KASAN CFLAGS switches are missing). I noticed that the lib/include/config/auto.conf file in the /lib/modules/xxx directory is different from the one in the kernel build directory, so I tried copying the auto.conf file from the kernel directory to lib/modules/xxx. At this point the individual files appear to compile with the same KASAN flags as the kernel, but the module build fails during the link step with missing symbols such as __asan_handle_no_return.

Is KASAN known to work with modules? If so, is any additional configuration needed for a module to use KASAN?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: KASAN actually works great for modules. Somehow I managed to botch the installation of the KASAN-ified kernel so that the module was compiling with old info. After reinstallation, the module compiled cleanly with KASAN and errors in the module are properly detected. Sorry for the false alarm here.